# slick afterchange event not triggering in mobile

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am using slick slider, and i am performing some functionality using angular js on slider's afterChange event. Its working fine in desktop while the afterchange event does not gets triggered in mobile, and hence my functionality does not run.

```
$('.slider').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {

  $scope.slickIndex = currentSlide;
  $('.dots').find('#photobookdiv' + $scope.slickIndex).click();
  $scope.selectedLeft = $scope.slickIndex;


});
```